# Variadic parameters get does not work

Tags: c++

I am creating CPP application that can create List's: string arrays. When initialization is called it get's variadic parameters and should insert them into a string array. It gives Segmentation error. Also if I remove Students_Second_Group.push(), everything works fine. Any suggestions?

```
// Main.cpp

#include "List.h"

int main() {
    List Students_First_Group(4), Students_Second_Group(3);
    Students_First_Group.push("Jonas Jonaits", "Tomas Tomaitis", "Petras Petraitis", "Donatas Petkevicius");
    Students_Second_Group.push("Mantas Jonaitis", "Tautvydas Tomaitis", "Linas Linaitis");
    return 0;
}

// List.h

#ifndef _LIST_H_
#define _LIST_H_
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cstdarg>
    using namespace std;

    class List {
    private:
        size_t size;
        vector<string> arr;
    public:
        List(int size);
        void push(const char* str...);
        ~List();
    };
#endif

// List.cpp

#include "List.h"

List::List(int s) {
    if(size > 0)
        size = s;
    else
        size = 10;
    arr = vector<string> (s);
}

void List::push(const char* str...) {
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, str);
    while (str) {
        arr.push_back(str);
        str = va_arg(arg, const char *);
    }
    va_end(arg);
}

List::~List() {}
```

Comment: using va_args is a c construct in C++ you should use varadic template

Comment: @Tyker can you provide some example?

Comment: 1) As described in the documentation of [`va_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg): "_If va_arg is called when there are no more arguments in ap, the behavior is undefined._" Hence, it should not return `nullptr` as you seem to expect. 2) "_can you provide some example?_": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298393/variadic-templates-example/37298596

Comment: The example at the end of [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) implements  a printf-like function with variadic templates, very close to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve your issue with varadic template but
because they are template varadic template should be put in the header

for more info http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class List {
    private:
    size_t size;
    vector<string> arr;
    void push() {}
    public:
    List(int size);
    template<typename ... Rest>
    void push(const char* first, Rest ... rest) {
        arr.push_back(first);
        push(rest...);
    }
    ~List();
    };

List::List(int s) {
    if(size > 0)
        size = s;
    else
        size = 10;
    arr = vector<string> (s);
}

List::~List() {}

int main() {
    List Students_First_Group(4), Students_Second_Group(3);
    Students_First_Group.push("Jonas Jonaits", "Tomas Tomaitis", "Petras Petraitis", "Donatas Petkevicius");
    Students_Second_Group.push("Mantas Jonaitis", "Tautvydas Tomaitis", "Linas Linaitis");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(arr.push_back(args), ...);` in C++17

Comment: Even simpler: define the base case as `void push() {}`, this way there's no need to repeat the push logic twice.

Comment: @GoranFlegar you can but it will allow for empty push calls

Comment: @Tyker true, but not if you make it private :) It depends if you want to allow empty calls or not.

Comment: @GoranFlegar you are, right i edited as you suggested

Comment: I don't get this answer.  The OP isn't using a variadic template.

Comment: nice answer, its just a bit unconnected, because the question is about variadic parameters, ie no templates, and the answer starts with "because they are template..."